# Determine wrong values and shift them between columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is my simplified CSV sample data:

```
Project;Step 1 Start;Step 1 End;Step 2 Start;Step 2 End;Step 3 Start;Step 3 End;Step 4 Start;Step 4 End;Step 5 Start;Step 5 End;Finish
A;01.01.2020;02.01.2020;02.01.2020;03.01.2020;03.01.2020;04.01.2020;04.01.2020;05.01.2020;05.01.2020;06.01.2020;06.01.2020
B;01.02.2020;02.02.2020;02.02.2020;03.02.2020;;;;;03.02.2020;04.02.2020;04.02.2020
C;01.03.2020;02.03.2020;02.03.2020;;;;;;;03.03.2020;03.03.2020
D;01.04.2020;;;;;;;;;02.04.2020;02.04.2020
E;01.05.2020;02.05.2020;02.05.2020;03.05.2020;;;03.05.2020;;;04.05.2020;04.05.2020
```

Reading the file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sampledata.csv", sep=";")
```

Data structure:

```
Project Step 1 Start  Step 1 End Step 2 Start  Step 2 End Step 3 Start  \
0       A   01.01.2020  02.01.2020   02.01.2020  03.01.2020   03.01.2020   
1       B   01.02.2020  02.02.2020   02.02.2020  03.02.2020          NaN   
2       C   01.03.2020  02.03.2020   02.03.2020         NaN          NaN   
3       D   01.04.2020         NaN          NaN         NaN          NaN   
4       E   01.05.2020  02.05.2020   02.05.2020  03.05.2020          NaN   

   Step 3 End Step 4 Start  Step 4 End Step 5 Start  Step 5 End      Finish  
0  04.01.2020   04.01.2020  05.01.2020   05.01.2020  06.01.2020  06.01.2020  
1         NaN          NaN         NaN   03.02.2020  04.02.2020  04.02.2020  
2         NaN          NaN         NaN          NaN  03.03.2020  03.03.2020  
3         NaN          NaN         NaN          NaN  02.04.2020  02.04.2020  
4         NaN   03.05.2020         NaN          NaN  04.05.2020  04.05.2020
```

- Each row represents one project
- Each project can run through different steps (in this simplified sample are only 5 projects and 5 steps. The original data has more than 100k projects and 40 steps)
- Each step has two columns. A "start" columns when projects enters the step and an "end" column, when project leaves the step
- Each project starts with "Step 1 Start" and ends in "Finish" but **not each step has to be followed**

#### My Problem:

Sometimes the "end" timestamp is written in the wrong column and i have to correct this with python. When finishing a project, the last "end" timestamp is written in "Step 5 End" and not in the last step "Step X End".

#### How to determine wrong values

If "Finish" and "Step 5 End" contains a timestamp and "Step 5 Start" is NaN.

#### How to correct wrong value

Check each step from 1 to n if "Start" and "End" contains a value.
If "Start" contains a value and "End" is empty, move timestamp from "Step 5 End" to "Step X End"

#### Expected sample data result

- Project A: All columns are filled, no correction necessary
- Project B: Step 3 and 4 were skipped, all "End" columns contain a timestamp. No correction necessary
- Project C: "Step 2 End" is empty, "Step 5 Start" is empty, "Step 5 End" contains value. So value from "Step 5 End" needs to shifted to "Step 2 End"
- Project D: "Step 5 End" needs to be shifted to "Step 1 End"
- Project E: "Step 5 End" needs to be shifted to "Step 4 End"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with

```
# get where the starts are not empty
arr_start = df.filter(like='Start').notna().to_numpy()
# get the end columns
df_end = df.filter(like='End')
# fillna the right missing value
df = df.fillna(df_end.bfill(axis=1)[arr_start&df_end.isna()])
# remove the values of the last step end if no value in the start of this step
df.loc[~arr_start[:,-1], df_end.columns[-1]] = np.nan

print (df)
  Project Step 1 Start  Step 1 End Step 2 Start  Step 2 End Step 3 Start  \
0       A   01.01.2020  02.01.2020   02.01.2020  03.01.2020   03.01.2020   
1       B   01.02.2020  02.02.2020   02.02.2020  03.02.2020          NaN   
2       C   01.03.2020  02.03.2020   02.03.2020  03.03.2020          NaN   
3       D   01.04.2020  02.04.2020          NaN         NaN          NaN   
4       E   01.05.2020  02.05.2020   02.05.2020  03.05.2020          NaN   

   Step 3 End Step 4 Start  Step 4 End Step 5 Start  Step 5 End      Finish  
0  04.01.2020   04.01.2020  05.01.2020   05.01.2020  06.01.2020  06.01.2020  
1         NaN          NaN         NaN   03.02.2020  04.02.2020  04.02.2020  
2         NaN          NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN  03.03.2020  
3         NaN          NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN  02.04.2020  
4         NaN   03.05.2020  04.05.2020          NaN         NaN  04.05.2020
```

One more explanation, `arr_start&df_end.isna()` allows to spot which step has a start and not a end, and using `bfill` will help to get the value in the last step end to the end step that need to be filled